# LiDAR to camera image fusion

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera, fusion, lidar

I want to fuse LiDAR `{X,Y,Z,1}` points on camera image `{u,v}` for which we have LiDAR points, camera matrix (`K`), distortion coefficient (`D`), position of camera and LiDAR (`x,y,z`), rotation of camera and LiDAR (`w+xi+yj+zk`). There are three coordinates system involved. Vehicle axle coordinate system(`X`:forward, `Y`:Left, `Z`: upward), LiDAR coordinate (`X`:Right, `Y`:Forward, `Z`: Up) and camera coordinate system (`X`: Right, `Y`:down, `Z`: Forward). I tried the below approach but the points are not fusing properly. All points are wrongly plotted.

Coordinate system:

For given Rotation and Position of camera and LiDAR we compute the translation using below equation.

```
t_lidar     = R_lidar  * Position_lidar^T
t_camera    = R_camera  *Position_camera^T
```

Then relative rotation and translation is computed as flows

```
R_relative = R_camera^T * R_lidar
t_relative = t_lidar -  t_camera
```

Then the final Transformation Matrix and point transformation between LiDAR Points `[X,Y,Z,1]` and image frame `[u,v,1]` is given by:

```
T =  [ R_relative | t_relative ] 
  [u,v,1]^T = K * T * [X,Y,Z,1]^T
```

Is there anything which I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

## Use opencv projectpoint directly

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints

[image]

C++: void projectPoints(InputArray objectPoints, InputArray rvec, InputArray tvec, InputArray cameraMatrix, InputArray distCoeffs, OutputArray imagePoints, OutputArray jacobian=noArray(), double aspectRatio=0 )

objectPoints – Array of object points, 3xN/Nx3 1-channel or 1xN/Nx1 3-channel (or vector ), where N is the number of points in the view.

rvec – Rotation vector. See Rodrigues() for details.

tvec – Translation vector.

cameraMatrix – Camera matrix